# Mapping UV coordinates to a plane in 3D space

Tags: vectors, plane-geometry

Suppose I have a quadrilateral *ABCD* in 3D space

`A----------B
 \          \
  \          \
   \          \
    C----------D`

And two-dimensional coordinates *(x,y)*, how can I "map" these coordinates onto *ABCD* to get 3D coordinates of the point on the quadrilateral.

For example, assuming that *AC = 2, CD = 4*,

- *(0,0) => A* because A is the top-left
- *(4,2) => D* because D is the bottom-right
- *(2,1) => The center of the quadrilateral on all axes*

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18663755/how-to-convert-a-3d-point-on-a-plane-to-uv-coordinates) on Stack Overflow is more or less the exact *opposite* of what I want to do.

Comment: The quadrilateral could be anywhere in 3-space.  When you say "plane" it appears you mean "quadrilateral."  In the typical coordinate system used in math if $A=(0,0),$ the $D=(4,-2),$ not $(4,2).$  You could simply  put a $z-$ coordinate of $0$ on each point to get a quadrilateral in 3-space.

Comment: You're right, I do mean quadrilateral. But i'm not sure what you mean by the rest of that

Comment: Suppose you have coordinates in the $xy-$plane.  You can embed the figure in 3-space simply by changing each coordinate $(x,y)$ to $(x,y,0).$  The coordinates of A would become $(0,0,0)$  Those of D would become $(4,2,0).$  There are infinitely many other ways to do it, which is what I meant by saying that the quadrilateral could be anywhere in 3-space.  As to your not using the coordinate system that's usual in math, are you perhaps doing computer graphics?  In computer graphics, it's usual to have $(0,0)$ at the top left and have the $y-$coordinate increase as you move down, but not in math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the 3-D coordinates of the point that corresponds to $A$ and unit vectors $\vec u$ and $\vec v$ that point in the directions of the edges $\overline{AB}$ and $\overline{AC}$, respectively, i.e., $$\vec u = {B-A\over \|B-A\|} \\ \vec v = {C-A\over\|C-A\|}.$$ The mapping you seek is then $(x,y)\mapsto A+x\vec u+y\vec v$. This is one of the simplest examples of a parametric surface patch. It’s often more convenient to set $\vec u=B-A$ and $\vec v=C-A$ so that the patch coordinates all lie in the interval $[0,1]$.